# qsub array job submission

Tags: arrays, bash, shell, unix, qsub

I am currently trying to run an array job on the "big-computer" at my Uni.

I'm new to Unix and bash and I've been having a hard time getting this to work.

The folder set up is as follow:

```
model1
- model1.inp
- model1.num
model2
- model2.inp
- model2.num
startup.sh
runAModel.sh
modelArray.sh
```

Due to restrictions on how long I can run a single job, I was asked to break up my simulations. So I need to run each model 5 times over, each time the model reads the input file .inp and outputs another input file for the subsequent run.

The code below used to work until a week a go or so but it doesn't seem to function anymore. I wonder if I didn't mess something up in there.

I suspected it might be in the line `qcmd="qsub -N $modelName -t 1:5 ../../modelArray.sh"` of `runAModel.sh` and that I should replace `1:5` to `1-5` but that didn't seem to work.

I use qstat to see my job and where I would expect to see a list of 5 queued jobs I only see one.

I was given three files to run:

`startup.sh` :

```
find . -mindepth 2 -type d  -exec ./runAModel.sh {} \;
```

`runAModel.sh` :

```
#!/bin/bash

echo starting model in $1

cd $1 # go into the model directory

modelName=$(basename $PWD)


for f in *
do
dos2unix $f
done

qcmd="qsub -N $modelName -t 1:5 ../../modelArray.sh"

qq=`$qcmd` # runs a qsub command

             # extract the job number

qt=`echo $qq | awk '{print $3}'`

jobid=${qt%%.*}

qrls $jobid.1
```

and `modelArray.sh` :

```
#!/bin/bash

# run program, invoke in model directory with input files.

# we want to run in the current working directory
#$ -cwd

# we want to run mpi with 4 cores on he same node:
#$ -pe sharedmem 4

# make a generous guess at the time we need
#$ -l h_rt=30:00:00

# force reservation
#$ -R y

# use 4G per process

#$ -l h_vmem=4G

# hold the array

#$ -h

echo I am task $SGE_TASK_ID in $JOB_ID with $SGE_TASK_LAST tasks in total

echo on $HOSTNAME
date
# run our model - set modules, then get the model name 

echo "set modules"

. /etc/profile.d/modules.sh

PROGRAMBUILD=/exports/programlocation
. $PROGRAMBUILD/loadModules.sh

modelName=$(basename $PWD)

echo mpirun -np 4  $PROGRAMBUILD/bin/program $modelName 
mpirun -np 4  $PROGRAMBUILD/bin/program $modelName 


if [ $SGE_TASK_ID == $SGE_TASK_LAST ]
then
    echo I am last task
else
    # release the next task....
    # next task in this array:
    next=$((SGE_TASK_ID+1))

    echo insert a test that this task in the array job was successful
    echo if so, release next task
    echo releasing $next
    ssh login01.***.uk qrls $JOB_ID.$next

    if [[ "$?" -ne 0 ]]; then
        echo failed to qrls $pid
    fi

fi
```

Comment: Why have you changed `1:5` into `1-5` provided that you have said it worked? Was it the cause, it would have never worked, wouldn't it?

Comment: I suggest to single quote the `{}`. And add `set -x` in every script in order to debug.

Comment: where about should the `set -x` go in each script ?

Comment: Just below the first line (`#!/bin/bash`).